# With apache2.4, how do I redirect requests for http://www.example.com to https://example.com

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-rewrite

I installed an SSL cert from LetsEncrypt on my apache2.4 vhost.

Now, requests for http://example.com go to https://example.com.

However, *some* browsers will not redirect http://www.example.com to https://example.com. Instead, they redirect https://www.example.com, and show a full-page security warning.

Presently, the rewrite rules in my config look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

How do I adjust the rules so that for all browsers, requests for http://www.example.com go to https://example.com?

Comment: If it is only _some_ browsers, they probably have the wrong redirection cached, especially if you used permanent redirect while still testing your rules.

Comment: @DusanBajic I'm talking about browsers visiting the site for the first time. For example, This behaviour doesn't occur on chrome on linux, but it occurs on browsers on some android devices.

Comment: Are there any other rules that might interfere, either in .htaccess or in server .conf (perhaps some that act based on User-Agent)?